# HTML5 video not loading in safari, or IE (even with flash fallback)

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-video

I have this working on Opera, Chrome and Firefox but for whatever reason the mp4 won't load in Safari and the flash fallback is ignored in IE although you can tell its trying to play because the poster image is there for a second and then vanishes, and then reappears after the length of the video. this is what I have in my HTML:

```
<video class="fullscreen-bg__video" id="background" poster="/images/videoframe.jpg" muted autoplay>
            <source src="/content/nationals.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2'>
            <source src="/content/nationals.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="/content/nationals.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            <object>
             <embed src="/content/nationals.flv" type= "application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="always" />
           </object>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

and the doctype for the page is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Any ideas as to whats incorrect? I've been at this almost all week on and off all week and I'm having no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the controls to your video tag like this:

```
<video controls="true" class="fullscreen-bg__video" id="background" poster="/images/videoframe.jpg" muted autoplay>
```